# Placing "Developer: Name" or "Design: Name" in footer

Tags: html, css

This's question for web designers with experience.

One wanted I create them a website. I've developed it. But there's one problem: he don't want typical "Created by Name" be placed at the bottom of the page, so he told to remove it.

Now I have one question. Do you place this unit (block) at sites that was created by yourself? What's matter of this unit? What to do if customer don't want to have it? What must I do?

I don't have really big experience in communicating with customers.

Thank you.

Comment: These details are specified in the contract signed by you and your client. Ideally you'd make sure to have a lawyer review the contract to be certain that it will be legally binding.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: This one should go to programmers.stackexchange.com. Anyway, IMHO the customer should decide, unless the contract says something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add it as a comment in the HTML source

```
<!--
# Site developed by: Yourname
-->
```

or your stylesheet:

```css
/**
 * SiteName Stylesheet 
 *
 * @author YourName | email@domain.com
 */
```